# How to query multiple aggregates efficiently with DDD?

Tags: repository, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

When I need to invoke some business method, I need to get all aggregate roots related to the operation, even if the operation is as primitive as the one given below (just adding item into a collection). What am I missing? Or is CRUD-based approach where you run one single query including table joins, selects and insert at the end - and database engine does all the work for you - actually better in terms of performance?

In the code below I need to query separate aggregate root (which creates another database connection and sends another select query). In real world applications I have been querying a lot more than one single aggregate, up to 8 for a single business action. How can I improve performance/query overhead?

## Domain aggregate roots:

```
class Device
{
    Set<ParameterId> parameters;

    void AddParameter(Parameter parameter)
    {
        parameters.Add(parameter.Id);
    }
}

class Parameter
{
    ParameterId Id { get; }
}
```

## Application layer:

```
class DeviceApplication
{
    private DeviceRepository _deviceRepo;
    private ParameterRepository _parameterRepo;

    void AddParameterToDevice(string deviceId, string parameterId)
    {
        var aParameterId = new ParameterId(parameterId);
        var aDeviceId = new DeviceId(deviceId);

        var parameter = _parameterRepo.FindById(aParameterId);
        if (parameter == null) throw;

        var device = _deviceRepo.FindById(aDeviceId);
        if (device == null) throw;

        device.AddParameter(parameter);
        _deviceRepo.Save(device);
    }
}
```

## Possible solution

I've been told that you can pass just an Id of another aggregate like this:

```
class Device
{
    void AddParameter(ParameterId parameterId)
    {
        parameters.Add(parameterId);
    }
}
```

But IMO it breaks incapsulation (by explicitely emphasizing term ID into the business), also it doesn't prevent from pasting wrong or otherwise incorrect identity (created by user).

And Vaughn Vernon gives examples of application services that use the first approach (passing whole aggregate instance).

Comment: Can I maybe add/remove directly IDS, not aggregates themselves?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is - don't query your aggregates at all.

An aggregate is a model that exposes behaviour, not data. Generally, it is considered a code smell to have getters on aggregates (ID is the exception). This makes querying a little tricky.

Broadly speaking there are 2 related ways to go about solving this. There are probably more but at least these don't break the encapsulation.

Option 1: Use domain events - 
By getting your domain (aggregate roots) to emit events which illustrate the changes to internal state you can build up tables in your database specifically designed for querying. Done right you will have highly performant, denormalised queryable data, which can be linearly scaled if necessary. This makes for very simple queries. I have an example of this on this blog post: [How to Build a Master-Details View when using CQRS and Event Sourcing](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/10/05/build-master-details-view-using-cqrs-event-sourcing/)

Option 2: Infer query tables - 
I'm a huge fan of option 1 but if you don't have an event sourced approach you will still need to persist the state of your aggregates at some point. There are all sorts of ways to do this but you could plug into the persistence pipeline for your aggregates a process whereby you extract queryable data into a read model for use with your queries.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I AM using domain events and separate read model / CQRS pattern. But in order to perform DOMAIN action I need to query those aggregates to get their IDs. Or are you suggesting that business methods should take IDs instead of aggregate roots? (I'm not using event soucing though, so I am saving domain object states and I need to query those, not some read model that could potentially be eventually consistent).

Comment: So when I need to add some Parameter to the Device, Device must have a method that accepts ParameterId, not the Parameter itself? That's not how Vaughn Vernon have done it. Currently my Device has a method that accepts Parameter itself, and inside it asks for the Id and saves it.

Comment: Assuming they are both AR then yes it must be by ID because AR represents the consistency boundary. However, if those models are within an AR then what you are doing is fine. Maybe you will find this helpful: [Inter-Aggregate Communication](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/11/22/4-secrets-inter-aggregate-communication-event-sourced-system/)

Comment: Then how do I know that given Id is of existing aggregate and not some bullshit generated by the client? We could end up with wrong references.

Comment: That's what validation is for.

Comment: Well, in order to validate identifier of an aggregate I will still need to go to data store and ask if this id exists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144487/discussion-between-codescribler-and-ewancoder).

Answer (score 1):

If you figured out that having RDBMS query with joins will work in this case - probably you have wrong aggregate boundaries.

For example - why would you need to load the `Parameter` in order to add it to the `Device`? You already have the identity of this `Parameter`, all you need to do is to add this id to the list of references `Parameters` in the `Device`. If you do it in order to satisfy your ORM - you're most probably doing something wrong.

Also remember that your aggregate *is* the transactional boundary. You really would want to complete all database operations inside one transaction and one connection.

Comment: Yes, you're quite correct. I have an Id and I can just append this Id to the list of Ids. It's just that my AddParameter method accepts Parameter aggregate root (not ParameterId value object) in favor of encapsulation and close cohesion between aggregates. And that leads to the need to assemble this other aggregate as well (just to get its Id afterwards).

Comment: You can encapsulate enough by using value objects as ids, so you will pass `ParameterId` object (struct) but this perfectly valid, you do not have to pass a pre-fetched aggregate. It is clear that aggregates never have any other type of reference to each other than just an id.

Comment: By encapsulation I meant business logic (pass parameter to device, not parameterId to device). All kinds of IDs is a little bit of encapsulation break because business don't care about Ids. And I'm already using value objects for ids. Anyway, if we pass `ParameterId` object - there's another issue raising: what if user will create random ParameterId object or invalid ParameterId object or some Id of already deleted aggregate? This is prevented automagically when you pass an aggregate itself.

Comment: Also, Vaughn Vernon in *Effective Aggregate Design II* gives an example of the same aggregate queries from multiple repositories as in my example.

Comment: I am looking at the paper now and cannot find what you are referring to. All is done using identity value objects. The only exception is the `ofTeam`. We do not see how the `ofTeam` is used. It might be that there are methods called or something. Because two other objects are not obtained but instead referenced only. The "generated" id issue is known. You must control your client. This is the *application service* and the *client* responsibility to ensure that the domain model works with correct data only.

Comment: Validity of an identity can be controller by some other way than fetching the whole aggregate from a repository... But again this is more to the application design and how do you trust your client, and who the client is.